# DLM model for data with seasonality

Tags: seasonality, dlm

I am trying to explore the changing relationship between two monthly time series data. DLM package in R comes into my attention as I would like to see the beta change between the two dataset $A$ (dependent) and $B$ (independent).

If I understand this correctly, the DLM model looks like this:

$$A_t = \beta_t B_t + v_t$$

$$\beta_t = G_t \beta_{t-1} + w_t$$

while $A_t$ and $B_t$ have significant seasonality and can be decomposed as follows:

$$A_t = \mathrm{Trend}_{A,t} + \mathrm{Seasonality}_{A,t} + \tilde v_t$$

$$B_t = \mathrm{Trend}_{B,t} + \mathrm{Seasonality}_{B,t} + \tilde w_t$$

My question is that since both dataset have significant seasonality, a `dlmModReg` for linear regression is obviously not enough. But I am not sure how I could add a seasonality component into my DLM model.

I am thinking fo the following script, but not quite sure how to use this in R. 
`myModel <- dlmModReg() + dlmModSeas(12)`

I am new to DLM modelling so any help or explaination would be greatly appreciated.